# Across an entire SharePoint-Online/365 site: List all currently open documents + the users that have them open

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sync, connection, lock

I'm doing a large migration of about 150GB of files out of a single SharePoint Site (the default "Team Site" for the 365 tenant), and into separate smaller sites.

I want to ensure that when I do this, that none of my users currently have any documents open/locked.

How can I see a current list of all currently open docs + the user(s) that have them open right now? (across the entire "Team Site")

And beyond my current task right now, this is something that I want to do at other times too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such method to display all open files in real time in SharePoint Online, we recommend you to migrate on non-working days.